# Google Gmail API oauth2.0 credentials for back end scripts

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail, google-workspace

I have a Google Cloud account, and set up a project that uses the GMAIL API.  I need full access so I can find an email in an inbox, get the attachment, and delete the email.  My script, which is written in PHP and uses the Google API PHP client library, works, but the first time it is run it requires the consent page, which I worked around since my script is not on a web server, but now I found after several weeks that the refresh token expired.

For some reason, I need to have a consent page set up, which makes no sense since I am only accessing the gmail inbox for my Google cloud account.  In the consent page setup, I don't have an option for internal users, and the hover popup suggests I need a workspace account?  Not sure what that is or why I need one, but OK, if I need one, how do I add that to my google cloud account?  There are no links anywhere in the cloud console, and if I google search it and go to a page that talks about workspaces, it only lets me see the page while logged into my personal Google Chrome account, when I switch to my business cloud account it redirects to some other page that has nothing to do with workspaces and no mention or link to it anywhere.  It's almost like workspaces has nothing to do with google API's, other than needing to be in one to use the API's for back end scripting?

Since I had to choose external users in the consent setup, I am stuck on testing mode, which I guess limits the refresh tokens to 7 days, which seems to be my issue.  But I can't go live with this project because that requires a YouTube video and a bunch of other garbage that has nothing whatsoever to do with my need to get credentials to access a back end service.  So again I am so confused after weeks of going in circles on this, I just need help figuring out what the heck it takes to simply get credentials from Google for use with an automated script.  I tried a service account but I guess the service account only works for read only access, you can't delete emails with it.  I also tried iMap access to get what I need, but I guess google disabled that a few months ago as well.

So bottom line, do I need a workspace account to be able to set up an internal user in the consent page so I don't have to make my project public so I can set my refresh token to never expire?  If so, how do I do that?  And if nobody knows how to do this, does anyone know of a company I can hire to walk me through it?  Has anyone tried the paid Google cloud support? As bad as the google cloud/developer/api pages are, I am hesitant to pay for support that takes weeks to get an answer that has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 0):

Sourced from https://justin.poehnelt.com/posts/google-user-credentials-as-application-default/.

You should be able to create a OAuth client for "Desktop app" and a consent screen that will allow you to persist a refresh token.

#### Create an OAuth consent screen

1. Open the
   [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) in a new tab or window.
2. Next to "Google Cloud Console," click the Down arrow
   [image: drop down arrow] and select your project.
3. At the top-left corner, click Menu [image: menu icon].
4. Click **APIs & Services** > **Credentials**. The credential page for your
   project appears.
5. Click **OAuth consent screen**. The "OAuth consent screen" screen
   appears.
6. Under "User Type," select **Internal**. If using an @gmail.com account, select **External**.
7. Click **Create**. An "Edit app registration" page appears.
8. Fill out the form:

   - In **App name**, enter a descriptive name. This will be visible to users.
   - In **User support email**, enter your personal email address.
   - Under **Developer contact information**, enter your personal email address.
9. Click **Save and Continue**. A Scopes form appears.
10. From the Scopes form, click **Save and Continue**. A summary appears.
11. Click **Back to Dashboard**.

> aside negative
>
> **Note:** When building a production add-on for the Google Workspace Marketplace, properly filling
> out the consent screen information is required prior to publishing.

#### Create Oauth credentials

1. Select the **Credentials** tab, click the **Create credentials** button and select **OAuth client ID**.
2. Select the application type **Desktop app**, enter a descriptive name, and click the **Create** button.
3. Click the file_download (Download JSON) button.
4. Rename your secret file to `client_secret.json`.

#### Start Oauth flow

```
gcloud auth application-default login --scopes "TODO" --client-id-file client_secret.json
```

Copy the credentials file: `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`

#### Get access token

You can use `gcloud` here to, but you don't need to.

```
GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token --scopes "TODO")
```

#### Use access token

```
curl https://someapi.googleapis.com/somepath \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Comment: The problem is, in order to publish I need to provide a youtube video, and provide a link to the app, and links to other info.  This is not a public app, it is not even a web app, it's just a script that runs on a server and uses the API.  And until I publish I can't select more than 7 days for the refresh token duration.  And I can't use internal without a workspace account.

Answer (score 0):

Using Oauth2 will always require that the user grant the application consent to access the users private data.

Once you are done with development you can set the app to production and your refresh tokens will stop expiring.

I think you are confused as a "google cloud account" does not have a gmail account a user has a gmail account. In this instance its your gmail account.

To create an internal app you need to be using a google workspace domain account to create the app.